# How to replace elements of preallocated np.array in Python, matlab style

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new in python coming from matlab. Now when i want to save a vector in matlab to a preallocated matrix i do this (matlab code)

```
a = zeros(5, 2)
b = zeros(5, 1)
# save elements of b in the first column of a
a(:, 1) = b
```

Now i am using numpy in python. I do not really know how to describe this problem. What am i doing here is essentially this

```
a = np.zeros([5, 2])
b = np.ones([5, 1])
a[:, 0] = np.reshape(b, a[:, 0].shape)
```

because the following solution is not working:

```
a[:, 0] = b # Not working
```

Can anyone point out other ways of doing it, more closely to the matlab style?

Comment: Does `b` have to be 2d, (5,1)?  Why not 1d, (5,)?  In matlab everything is 2d.  Not so in numpy.  Learn the difference early.

Comment: `a[:,0] = b.ravel()` is a simpler way of doing the `b` reshape.   Or `a[:,0] = b[: 0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way would be -

```
a[:,[0]] = b
```

Sample run -

```
In [217]: a = np.zeros([5, 2])
     ...: b = np.ones([5, 1])
     ...: 

In [218]: a[:,[0]] = b

In [219]: a
Out[219]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Basically with this slicing of using a scalar `a[:,0]`, number of dimensions are reduced (the dimension along which the scalar is used is removed) for assignment. When we specify a list of index/indices like `a[:,[0]]`, the dimensions are preserved, i.e. kept as `2D` and that allows us to assign `b`, which is also `2D`. Let's test that out -

```
In [225]: a[:,0].shape
Out[225]: (5,) # 1D array

In [226]: a[:,[0]].shape
Out[226]: (5, 1) # 2D array

In [227]: b.shape
Out[227]: (5, 1) # 2D array
```

For reference, here's a [**`link`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to the slicing scheme. Quoting the relevant part from it -

> An integer, i, returns the same values as i:i+1 except the
> dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1.
>
> In particular, a selection tuple with the p-th element an integer (and all other
> entries :) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1.